# Getting Rid of Extraneous Characters in a String-Javascript

Tags: javascript, json, string

I am loading data about NBA games from an API using Javascript, and I want to manipulate it but am having trouble. Each game is its own separate object, and is the data is returned like this:

```
Date: "Nov 7, 2014"
Opponent: "@ Charlotte"
Result: "L"
Score: "122-119"
Spread: "+1.5"
```

Depending on whether the team is home or away, there is either a "@" or a "vs" in front of the name of the opponent for that particular game. I want to get rid of this, so that the "Opponent" key only has "Charlotte" as its value in the above example.

I've tried using
`gameLog[i].Opponent = (gameLog[i].Opponent.split(" ").pop`

to get rid of any characters before the space, but this ruins the data when there is a team name with a space in it like "New York" or "Los Angeles"

Comment: have you considered looking at using regular expressions?

Comment: I'm not overly familiar with regular expressions, but how would you solve this using them?

Comment: @BenMelito I just added an answer with a regular expression

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This takes the string, and creates a new substring starting at the index of the first white space. e.g.:

@ New York = a new string starting after the @. -> New York

```
gameLog[i].Opponent = gameLog[i].Opponent.substr(gameLog[i].Opponent.indexOf(' ')+1);
```

Comment: Can you provide more of an explanation of what that is actually doing?  It would make for a better answer.

Comment: It takes the string, and creates a new substring starting at the index of the first white space.

e.g.: @ New York = a new string starting after the @. -> New York

Answer (score 0):

I guess, something along these lines might help.

```
var home = "@ Charlotte";
var opponent = "vs New York";

function parse(team){

    // Case when it is a home team
    if ( team.indexOf("@") === 0 ){

    return team.replace("@","").trim();

  // Away team
  } else {

    return team.replace("vs","").trim();

  }

}

console.log( parse(home) );
console.log( parse(opponent) );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
gameLog[i].Opponent = (gameLog[i].Opponent.split(" ").slice(1).join(" "));
```

1. Split based off space character
2. Slice off the first item in the array
3. Join the contents of the array back together with space.

Answer (score 0):

You need the [`substr()`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_substr.asp) method:

```
var str = "@ Charlotte";
var res = str.substr(2);
```

Result: `Charlotte`

Unless there is also a space after "vs", which is not clear.

Then you could use:

```
var str = "@ Charlotte";
var res = str.substr(str.indexOf(' ')+1);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expressions to replace unwanted characters while looping over an array of objects.

```
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
      arr[i].Opponent = arr[i].Opponent.replace(/@\s|vs\s/g, '');
}
```

Here's a [jsbin](https://jsbin.com/fohugesumu/edit?html,js,console)